# Overriding an Equals method in Java

Tags: java, overriding

Basically, I have to override for the equals method of object Employee.

I tried

```
public boolean equals( Object b ){
   if (this == b) return true; 
   if ( ! (b instanceof Employee) )
      return false;
   final other=(Employee)b;
   return getID()==other.getID();
}
```

but received an Error:

```
Employee.java:28: error: <identifier> expected 

   final other=(Employee)b;
```

```
public boolean equals( Object b ) 
{ 
  if ( ! (b instanceof Employee) ) 
    return false;
```

Comment: *final* ***Employee*** *other = (Employee) b;*

Comment: what type is ID? just curious.

Comment: @Stultuske This is not really relevant to the question

Comment: @Frontear yet it might be very relevant to the follow up question. Either way, it not being the answer to the question at hand, is why I posted it as a comment, not as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You have a syntax error.  Variables in java require a type.

```
final Employee other = (Employee) b;
```

will do.

Answer (score 1):

Use `final Employee other=(Employee)b;` insted of `final other=...`

JAVA always need an identifier for variables or functions